# Dependent column constraints

Tags: mysql, sql

Not sure if I can achieve this using a `mysql` constraint, but in a table like

```
CREATE TABLE constraint_table (
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int NOT NULL
)
```

is it possible to have a `mysql` constraint such that `col2` can have duplicates for a given `col1`

```
| id | col1 | col2 |
| 1  | 1    | 1    | 
| 2  | 1    | 2    |
| 3  | 1    | 1    |
```

but the `col2` values used by a specific `col1` value cannot be used by another `col1` value again

```
| id | col1 | col2 |
| 1  | 1    | 1    | 
| 2  | 1    | 2    |
| 3  | 1    | 1    | 
| 4  | 2    | 1    | invalid - as 1 is included in col2 values where col1 <> 2 (need to restrict this)
| 5  | 2    | 2    | invalid - as 2 is included in col2 values where col1 <> 2 (need to restrict this)
| 6  | 2    | 4    | valid - as 4 is not included in col2 values where col1 <> 2
```

and the valid table should looks like

```
| id | col1 | col2 |
| 1  | 1    | 1    | 
| 2  | 1    | 2    |
| 3  | 1    | 1    |
| 4  | 2    | 3    |
| 5  | 2    | 4    |
| 6  | 2    | 4    |
```

Sorry for the bad title, I'm not sure how to call this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Have a fun!

```
CREATE TABLE ref_data (
  col1 INT NOT NULL,
  col2 INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX (col1),
  UNIQUE KEY (col2)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE constraint_table (
  id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  col1 int NOT NULL,
  col2 int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT cn_col FOREIGN KEY (col1,col2)
REFERENCES ref_data (col1,col2)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Thanks! it works as expected but just curious if its possible without creating a new table.

Comment: You can not do it with one table and constraint. But you can create one table and one [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong data format.  You seem to want one value of `col1` for each `col2`.  That suggests a table for this purpose:

```
create table2 (
    col2 int primary key,
    col1 int not null,
);
```

Then your table can be:

```
CREATE TABLE constraint_table (
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    col2 int NOT NULL,
    . . . -- I assume there are other tables here
    foreign key (col2) references table2(col2)
);
```

`col1` doesn't belong in this table, because it is strictly dependent on `col2`.  So, the pair goes in the first table -- with one row.

Comment: Thanks! i got your idea and it works as expected. i was just curious if its possible without creating a new table.

Comment: @nambi . . . Probably not.  You are dealing with denormalized data.  Foreign key relationships are part of maintaining data integrity for normalized data (they can work in other situations), so they may not easily work in this case.